# Can I dump BOBJ reports into SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports

I wanted to see if it is possible to dump BOBJ reports straight into a SharePoint Online library?

Currently we have a number of BOBJ reports that we email out daily to a number of people but thought it would be easier to get this process automated and to have all the required users go to a SharePoint library to access their required report.

If this is a possibility, how would we go about setting this up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alert for all the pertinent users so they would get an email anytime a file was added to a library.

Comment: Thank you but I need a way to automatically send BOBJ reports to a SharePoint Online library before I create an alert system for the users.